# mod rewrite for url with multiple variables

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is the URL i am trying to rewrite.
http://360bowling.com/tournament/?tid=1&tpn=this-is-a-test

can I rewrite this to 
http://360bowling.com/tournament/this-is-a-test

I ahve tried several combinations in my .htaccess but none have worked

I have very little knowledge of mod rewrite, so I'm mainly just guessing.

this is a WordPress site so the normal WP stuff is in .htaccess

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tournament/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ tournament/index.php?tid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: RewriteRule (.*)?tid=1&tpn=/(.*) [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/?tid=1&tpn=/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tournament/([^/.]+)/?$ tournament/?tid=$1 [L] <- this one was before I added the tpn variable
RewriteRule    ^tournament/([0-9]+)/?$    tournament/=$1    [NC,L]   <- this one was before I added the tpn variable

Comment: I have read and read but I don't really understand the subject.  Nothing works I ahve tried, at all.

Comment: The urls are pulled from a custom table that is not part of the wordpress structure so permalinks won't work. I create a plugin with all custom tables to increase efficiency of the search functions.  I just don't know much about this subject :/